# Python: list and string matching

Tags: python, match

I have following:

```
temp = "aaaab123xyz@+"

lists = ["abc", "123.35", "xyz", "AND+"]

for list in lists
  if re.match(list, temp, re.I):
    print "The %s is within %s." % (list,temp)
```

The re.match is only match the beginning of the string, How to I match substring in between too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

It also seems like you don't really need regular expressions here. Your regular expression `123.35` probably doesn't do what you expect because the dot matches anything.

If this is the case then you can do simple string containment using `x in s`.

Comment: yeah, yours is 5 seconds faster actually, +1

Answer (score 13):

Use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) or just use in `if l in temp:`

**Note**: built-in type `list` should not be shadowed, so `for l in lists:` is better

Comment: I would have to agree for simple substring matching `in` is a lot easier than re.search.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a slightly more complex check using `map` and `any`.

```
>>> temp = "aaaab123xyz@+"
>>> lists = ["abc", "123.35", "xyz", "AND+"]
>>> any(map(lambda match: match in temp, lists))
True
>>> temp = 'fhgwghads'
>>> any(map(lambda match: match in temp, lists))
False
```

I'm not sure if this is faster than a compiled regexp.